# Django haystack with elasticsearch, indexing issue

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

Im using django-haystack with elasticsearch but there is a problem with indexing. When rebuilding my index

```
 python manage.py rebuild_index
```

following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 210, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 256, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 78, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 177, in update
    self.conn.bulk_index(self.index_name, 'modelresult', prepped_docs, id_field=ID)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/pyelasticsearch/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 95, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/pyelasticsearch/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 366, in bulk_index
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/pyelasticsearch/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 221, in send_request
    **({'data': request_body} if body else {}))
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 387, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 345, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/requests/requests/sessions.py", line 448, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palo/.virtualenvs/toro/src/requests/requests/adapters.py", line 324, in send
    raise Timeout(e)
Timeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Request timed out. (timeout=10)
Timeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Request timed out. (timeout=10)
```

I used django-haystack - 2.0.0-beta, pyelasticsearch - 0.5, elasticsearch 0.20.6, java version "1.6.0_24"

**Haystack Settings**

```
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
            'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
            'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        },
    }
```

And Im sure my elasticsearch serivce is running.

Comment: It sounds like your ElasticSearch instance is unavailable. What's the result of "curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'"? You should see JSON output with the server status and version.

Comment: Is this solved or not

Answer (score 16):

This does not necessarily mean that your es server is down, especially if you get something reasonable returned with `curl -I "127.0.0.1:9200"`. More likely, this is an issue of your request simply not getting enough time given the speed of connections involved.

Interestingly, the default timeout set in pyelasticsearch is 60 seconds, see `def __init__(self, urls, timeout=60, max_retries=0, revival_delay=300):` in https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch/blob/master/pyelasticsearch/client.py. However, haystack overwrites that with its default setting, which is 10 seconds, as per `self.timeout = connection_options.get('TIMEOUT', 10)` in https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/__init__.py.

As you can see though, haystack allows you to easily modify your setting, by adding `'TIMEOUT': 60,` to your engine configuration.

And solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I too had  the  similar  problem

sudo service elasticsearch restart

then it worked

Comment: This solved my problem after my server had run out of disk space.

Answer (score -2):

are you running

```
bin/elasticsearch -f
```

I think you are not running the searchengine.